# Question about error message PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am copying data into PostgreSQL and received the following error message

The code I used is

```
COPY gdp FROM 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data\gdp.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Error message received:

```
ERROR: extra data after last expected column
SQL state: 22P04
Context: COPY gdp, line 2: ""Abilene, TX",5.90,0.00,-0.54,-0.09,0.09,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.19,-0.07,0.52,0.00,0.24,0.00"
```

I have checked the value of line 2 and no additional space in the variable. I couldn't figure out which column that causes this error.

Here are the columns I set up so far for this table. I am new to PostgreSQL so any help you can provide is appreciated.

msa character varying NOT NULL,

gdp_perc numeric,

natural_resource_mining numeric,

construction numeric,

durable_goods_manf numeric,

non_durable_manf numeric,

trade numeric,

transportation_utilities numeric,

information numeric,

finance_property numeric,

professional_business_serv numeric,

education_medical numeric,

art_food_entertainment numeric,

gov numeric,

CONSTRAINT gdp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (msa)

Here is the look of my table
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just noticed that I left out one column. All is well now.